# read a file from an specific rows and column matlab R2011

Tags: matlab

I have a textfile with the name 'RefrencePointCloud' includes header like:

```
22.5992 30.9355 0.5685
0.90672936 -0.42171113 -0.00126307
0.42171150 0.90673007 0.00002968
0.00113275 -0.00055956 0.99999920
0.90672936 -0.42171113 -0.00126307 0.00000000
25.532  32.090  3.433   0.254
25.537  32.082  3.435   0.250
25.544  32.074  3.438   0.250
25.551  32.066  3.442   0.250
25.558  32.058  3.445   0.254
25.564  32.050  3.448   0.250
25.572  32.042  3.452   0.250
25.578  32.033  3.454   0.250
25.585  32.026  3.458   0.250
```

and Now I want to read this file from row 6 till end with only the frist three columns! in matlab R2014b I wrote below code and it works fine  `PTX_Data_Raw = dlmread(RefrencePointCloud,' ',[5 0 : 3]);`
but when I run my code in matlab R2011a via my GUI app, it gives me the error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions!" whereas my GUI run perfectly in Matlab R2014b!
is there any solution for solving this issue to make compatible my GUI in both version of Matlab?

Comment: According to the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html) it should be supported. Can you paste the full error message? It might give some indication to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Please read the tag-descriptions when using them. Not a single tag matched your question, fixed that.